# Extracting data from 1st table and using its value to extract data from other table

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a follow mechanism for my blog which is a part of website. So when a `user` wants to follow the other `user` he click on the follow button and in a `table: follow`, his `email_id` and the `to-be-follow-user's email_id`  is inserted. Now when I want to show the blog of the followed user's on a page, I extract the data from `follow table`, which contains all the `email_id's` of the user I followed and then I want to use these `email_id's` to extract the data from `blog table` against all the user's (that I followed) `email_id` I got.

The problem is I can't do this second part, extracting data from second table, I am getting all the email's I followed but couldn't get their blogs.

Finally I posted the code.

```
$query= "select follow_user from follow where my_email='".$_SESSION['email']."'";

$data=mysql_query($query);
if (!$data) { // add this check.
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error()) ;
}

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($data)){
    echo $row['follow_user'];
    echo "<br>";
    $query="select * from blog where my_email='".$row['follow_user']."'";
    $data=mysql_query($query);
    if (!$data) { // add this check.
        die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error()) ;
    }
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($data)){
        echo $row['subject'];
        echo "<br>";
        echo $row['my_email'];
        echo "<br>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get related data from two tables is to use a `JOIN`.

More information on `JOIN` here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

example:

```
SELECT blog.entry
FROM blog
INNER JOIN follow ON blog.email_id = follow.followed_email_id
WHERE follow.email_id = 32
```

This will get you all the entry fields from blog written by various followed_email_id where the follower email_id is 32.

The inner join makes sure you get things that match and only those things that match.

---

**Update for new code above:**

You still only need one query.  Doing a lot of queries in a loop will kill your database if it's in a real production environment.

Your code becomes a lot simpler and can only fail because of an invalid query one time:

```
$query= "
    SELECT blog.*, follow.follow_user
    FROM blog
    INNER JOIN follow ON blog.my_email = follow.follow_user
    WHERE follow.follow_user = {$_SESSION['email']}
";

$data=mysql_query($query);
if (!$data) { // add this check.
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error()) ;
}

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($data)){
    echo $row['follow_user'];
    echo "<br>";
    echo $row['subject'];
    echo "<br>";
    echo $row['my_email'];
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Buddy this didn't get me what I wanted, its showing data on the basis of two equal parameter in two table, but I want to extract some parameter from one table and then on the basis of these extracted parameter I want to extract the table in other. These parameter can be many and many that too different

Comment: @user3417110 Yeah, but it's showing you the principle of joining tables, so that should get you where you want to go

Comment: Can you please help me with the working code according to the code I posted abouve

Comment: @user3417110 `JOIN` is how you do that extraction all in one step. Updated the answer with what you want.